# Jetty on Android warns SSLException

Tags: android, ssl, jetty

This happens only on Android and very often. HTTPS works, but perhaps this (exception) is the reason for slowing down the speed.

IGNORE!!!javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Inbound is closed before close_notify alert has been received.
    at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLEngineImpl.closeInbound(SSLEngineImpl.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.closeInbound(SslConnection.java:698)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ssl.SslConnection$DecryptedEndPoint.fill(SslConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

It uses Bouncy Castle crypto-provider version 1.60.

Comment: If you see `com.android.org.conscrypt` in your stacktrace then you are using conscrypt, not bouncycastle.

Comment: No, conscrypt is default Android crypto-provider, and all staff are done by chosen provider:
...
Security.removeProvider("BC"); //remove Android's BC
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider()); //add original BC
...
KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "BC");//using BC
...

Previous SpongyCastle 1.58 gives the same exception.
Maybe the best choice is switching to conscrypt, but it will take a time, and can conscrypt do all staff (generating CA then HTTPS certificates, file encryption and signing...)?